# How to submit a form using jQuery Validate submitHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

this is jQuery submit form code. what i like to know is how can i submit the form on using submitHandler. thanks in advance.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do other stuff for a valid form
    $.post('thankyou.php', $("#confrom").serialize(), function(data) {
        $("#confrom").fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('#results').html(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Based on the original wording of your OP & title, do you realize that the `submitHandler` is an option of the `.validate()` method, which is part of the jQuery Validate plugin?  Otherwise, your code looks fine and it ***will*** submit the form via Ajax.  **Clearly explain your problem, the desired results and the actual results.**

Answer (score 1):

There is a `submitHandler` built into the plugin that contains something like `form.submit()`.  Since you're over-riding that with your own custom `submitHandler`, you still need to use the `submit`.  Otherwise, in your case, simply do some kind of Ajax instead of `.submit()`.

The `submitHandler` goes inside of the `.validate()` method.  In order to use the `.validate()` method, you must first include the jQuery Validate plugin after you include jQuery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#yourform').validate({
        // other options,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('thankyou.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
                $("#confrom").fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```